# Thymeleaf many-to-many checkbox list

Tags: java, list, checkbox, many-to-many, thymeleaf

I am porting an application from JSP to Thymeleaf.  So far i have found an equivalent to everything I was doing in JSP EXCEPT for this.  I have a role entity that has a many-to-many relationship with the permission entity, probably a very typical setup.  In JSP I used to be able to edit the role and map each permission to a checkbox, like this :

```
<form:checkboxes element="li" items="${systemPermissions}" path="permissions" itemValue="id" itemLabel="name" id="systemPermissions"/>
```

This takes a List object from the model and maps all the allowed permissions by checking each checkbox accordingly.  Super simple, super concise, but unfortunately I am not finding a way to do this with Thymeleaf.

Is there a way with Thymeleaf to dynamically create a checkbox list and map a many-to-many relationship to it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with a snippet like the following (assuming you put the All Permissions as a List and Allowed Permissions for a role as a Map in the model):

```
<thbody>
 <td>
  <th:block th:each="p: ${AllPermissions}">
   <input type="checkbox" name="perms" th:value="${p.id}" 
 th:checked="${#maps.containsKey(AllowedPermissionsForRole, p.id)}" /> <label th:text="${p.permissionsName}"></label>
  </th:block>
 </td>
</thbody>
```

By the way here i put all check boxes in a table cell but you can understand the idea. We are just iterating over all available permissions the see whether we have it in our currently selected role's permissions or not.

Comment: Thank you for your response!  How does the underlying controller then map these checkboxes back to entities when the form is sent?

Comment: Check this SO link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679777/map-checkboxes-to-list-using-sprint-boot-and-thymeleaf You can just take checked values as a List of String and then add/match them to your entity

Comment: I can confirm this works!  Pretty amazing what Thymeleaf can do.  Thanks for your help!